# Oracle SQL, how to select first row in a group?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

Here is the my SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75ab7/2

Basically, I have created a table and insert some data into it.

```
CREATE TABLE subject (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  seq_num INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO subject 
  (id, seq_num, name) 
VALUES 
  (1, 1, 'sub_1_1');

INSERT INTO subject 
  (id, seq_num, name) 
VALUES 
  (2, 1, 'sub_1_2');

INSERT INTO subject 
  (id, seq_num, name) 
VALUES 
  (3, 2,'sub_2_1');

INSERT INTO subject 
  (id, seq_num, name) 
VALUES 
  (4, 2, 'sub_2_2');

INSERT INTO subject 
  (id, seq_num, name) 
VALUES 
  (5, 2, 'sub_2_3');

INSERT INTO subject 
  (id, seq_num, name) 
VALUES 
  (6, 3, 'sub_3_1');

INSERT INTO subject 
  (id, seq_num, name) 
VALUES 
  (7, 3, 'sub_3_1');
```

I run this select statement:

```
select
  LISTAGG(TRIM(id), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) AS IDS,
  seq_num,
  LISTAGG(TRIM(name), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) AS NAMES
from
  subject
group by
  seq_num
order by
  seq_num asc
```

The select statement result:

```
| ids   | seq_num | names                   |
|-------|---------|-------------------------|
| 1,2   | 1       | sub_1_1,sub_1_2         |
| 3,4,5 | 2       | sub_2_1,sub_2_2,sub_2_3 |
| 6,7   | 3       | sub_3_1,sub_3_1         |
```

Can I generate something like this?

```
| ids | seq_num | names   |
|-----|---------|---------|
| 1   | 1       | sub_1_1 |
| 3   | 2       | sub_2_1 |
| 6   | 3       | sub_3_1 |
```

That is only pick the first row in a group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `keep` and `first` in oracle:

```
select seq_num,
       max(trim(id)) keep (dense_rank first order by trim(id)) as first_id,
       max(trim(name)) keep (dense_rank first order by trim(id)) as first_name
from subject
group by seq_num
order by seq_num asc;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75ab7/11) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Can you please explain the significance to use Trim() here?

Comment: @Harshil . . . That is a question for the OP and should be asked on the question.  The `trim()` is used in the code in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Use row number:

```
select
    id, seq_num, name
from
(
    select id, seq_num, name,
        row_number() over (partition by seq_num order by id) rn
    from subject
) t
where rn = 1
order by seq_num;
```

Here is a link to your updated Fiddle:

## Demo

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select
  min(id) AS IDS,
  seq_num,
  min(name) AS NAMES
from
  subject
group by
  seq_num
order by
  seq_num asc;
```

[Working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75ab7/6/0)

Hope it helps!